# Missing dependency LombokGetSetter.jar ver 1.0

Tags: java, maven, annotations, dependencies, lombok

I got assigned a task to bring an old web application to life. It's built using maven and the annotation processor - Lombok.

After spending hours tinkering with it and trying to match different JDK to NetBeans I believe there's one more thing I can't seem to resolve.

There's a dependency LombokGetSetter that seems to be missing. I tried googling for it but to no avail and it's not on any of the repositories. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly: you could not resolve the dependency to Lombok library? Or did you resolve it but it still shows errors in your IDE?

Comment: Whatever that jar file is, it doesn't seem to be something that is part of core Lombok, or at least there's no mention of it at [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org).  What is trying to reference it, and how, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a lombok developer I can tell you that we never created such a jar.